# How can I use queues in python and find the subset of matching values of two functions?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

```
import time
import multiprocessing as mp

start = time.time()

def square(i):
    return i**2

def add(i):
    return i

def sigma_sum(start, stop, expression):
    return sum(expression(i) for i in range(start, stop))

def foo(q):
    for n in range(1000):
        q.put(list(sigma_sum(1, n, add)))

def bar(r):
    for k in range(1000):
        r.put(list(sigma_sum(1, k, square)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = mp.Queue()
    r = mp.Queue()
    mp1 = mp.Process(target=foo, args = (q,))
    mp2 = mp.Process(target=bar, args = (r,))
    mp1.start()
    mp2.start()
    print(set(q.get()) & set(r.get()))

end = time.time()

print((start-end)*-1)
```

I adjusted this code to try to work with queues but so far I have had absolutely no success. I'm getting errors like:

```
>File "/Users/crxunch/temp2.py", line 17, in foo
   >q.put(list(sigma_sum(1, n, add)))
>TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

and

```
>File "/Users/crxunch/temp2.py", line 21, in bar
>   r.put(list(sigma_sum(1, k, square)))
>TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

If anyone could provide any help oh this I would really appreciate it.

Comment: "sigma_sum" returns a single number which can't be converted to a list.

Answer (score 0):

right now

```py
def sigma_sum(start, stop, expression):
    return sum(expression(i) for i in range(start, stop))
```

returns a single value (int/float), and you call it like so

```py
q.put(list(sigma_sum(1, n, add)))
```

where you try to create a list from this single element, that s there the error comes from.

to solve the problem eather change the sigma_sum function to return a list or change the put lines so you don't try to make a list of a single element

Comment: this is true but when I would do something like
```a = sigma_sum(1, n, add)
list1.append(a)```
I would get a valid list that I could work with

Comment: then you can just replace a in append by a so that it gives you : list1.append(sigma_sum(1, n, add)). this should work :)

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple issues:

1. First and foremost, you have `q.put(list(sigma_sum(1, n, add)))` but the `list` constructor requires an *iterable* yet sigma_sum computes a single int value, which is not an *iterable*.
2. Your main process is expecting a single value in each queue, but `foo` and `bar` are each *attempting* to write 1000 values to their respective queues.
3. You should move the definitions of `start` and `end` to within the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block.
4. Your computation of the running time can be simplified (requires no multiplication):

```py
import time
import multiprocessing as mp

def square(i):
    return i**2

def add(i):
    return i

def sigma_sum(start, stop, expression):
    return sum(expression(i) for i in range(start, stop))

def foo(q):
    q.put([sigma_sum(1, n, add) for n in range(1000)])

def bar(r):
    r.put([sigma_sum(1, k, add) for k in range(1000)])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()

    q = mp.Queue()
    r = mp.Queue()
    mp1 = mp.Process(target=foo, args=(q,))
    mp2 = mp.Process(target=bar, args=(r,))
    mp1.start()
    mp2.start()
    print(set(q.get()) & set(r.get()))
    mp1.join()
    mp2.join()

    end = time.time()

    print(end - start)
```

Prints:

```None
{0, 1, 391170, 3, 468996, 378885, 6, 28680, 10, 15, 491536, 143380, 21, 20503, 323610, 28, 14365, 362526, 2080, 348195, 36, 163878, 98346, 309291, 118828, 45, 430128, 22578, 53301, 55, 10296, 63546, 43071, 8256, 66, 452676, 440391, 6216, 258121, 397386, 92235, 180300, 78, 75855, 372816, 41041, 489555, 208981, 16471, 4186, 91, 110685, 45150, 18528, 2145, 278631, 105, 198765, 319600, 233586, 12403, 231540, 467061, 69751, 120, 235641, 145530, 352380, 229503, 32896, 411778, 292995, 153735, 136, 237705, 299151, 270480, 419986, 227475, 39060, 116886, 159895, 153, 487578, 30876, 51360, 239778, 2211, 34980, 65703, 171, 26796, 47278, 225456, 24753, 4278, 286903, 6328, 260281, 94395, 190653, 190, 73920, 8385, 403651, 241860, 207046, 14535, 10440, 366796, 104653, 184528, 210, 223446, 450775, 305371, 315615, 100576, 20706, 485605, 2278, 231, 465130, 356590, 243951, 147696, 428275, 438516, 28920, 170236, 253, 131328, 221445, 129286, 22791, 37128, 174345, 133386, 108811, 16653, 196878, 114960, 12561, 383250, 4371, 276, 389403, 127260, 57630, 84255, 166176, 18721, 246051, 135460, 59685, 82215, 6441, 2346, 280875, 300, 49455, 86320, 262450, 272691, 483636, 67896, 155961, 377146, 55611, 219453, 205120, 125250, 8515, 96580, 325, 178503, 80200, 334153, 72010, 338253, 137550, 61776, 395605, 10585, 88410, 330078, 351, 248160, 463203, 43365, 311655, 342378, 418155, 409965, 448878, 2415, 41328, 4465, 14706, 162165, 149878, 123256, 360825, 378, 53628, 217470, 295296, 33153, 78210, 188805, 481671, 139656, 45451, 326028, 24976, 371091, 27028, 31125, 406, 113050, 6555, 289180, 90525, 63903, 346528, 301476, 436645, 250278, 39340, 35245, 20910, 102831, 12720, 435, 264628, 2485, 182710, 195000, 426426, 121278, 401856, 203203, 16836, 8646, 215496, 106953, 4560, 465, 141778, 322003, 76245, 23005, 479710, 274911, 461280, 51681, 47586, 18915, 98790, 29161, 10731, 70125, 350703, 496, 252405, 283128, 92665, 158203, 2556, 307720, 446985, 152076, 6670, 528, 66066, 119316, 37401, 213531, 365085, 14878, 172578, 168490, 143916, 4656, 561, 318003, 111156, 387640, 477753, 381501, 266815, 74305, 2628, 416328, 8778, 176715, 254541, 201295, 12880, 595, 186966, 354903, 434778, 408156, 459361, 164451, 393828, 49770, 193131, 94830, 25200, 57970, 375411, 630, 211575, 117370, 21115, 17020, 27261, 10878, 60031, 6786, 33411, 424581, 297606, 55945, 291466, 43660, 2701, 31375, 41616, 4753, 277140, 146070, 105111, 475800, 666, 101025, 180901, 19110, 445096, 68265, 314028, 256686, 62128, 154290, 23220, 35511, 45753, 84666, 82621, 703, 400065, 303810, 53956, 39621, 72390, 15051, 160461, 285390, 8911, 86736, 269011, 2775, 359128, 80601, 369370, 29403, 209628, 109278, 336610, 199396, 741, 457446, 332520, 115440, 13041, 4851, 340725, 6903, 473851, 97020, 88831, 131841, 129795, 64261, 328455, 780, 78606, 133903, 148240, 11026, 432915, 127765, 47895, 258840, 232221, 234270, 344865, 2850, 52003, 230181, 191271, 236328, 414505, 37675, 135981, 185136, 820, 17205, 228150, 125751, 238395, 310078, 324415, 170820, 498501, 90951, 21321, 207690, 443211, 406351, 226128, 25425, 279378, 422740, 9045, 4950, 240471, 174936, 385881, 138075, 76636, 861, 166753, 471906, 70500, 349030, 27495, 156520, 123753, 19306, 379756, 7021, 2926, 455535, 271216, 363378, 224115, 103285, 113526, 392055, 15225, 496506, 242556, 66430, 293761, 197506, 33670, 903, 31626, 261003, 23436, 320400, 13203, 299925, 107416, 140185, 150426, 179101, 222111, 99235, 50086, 11175, 93096, 244650, 121771, 287661, 162735, 373680, 41905, 946, 494515, 43956, 5050, 3003, 205761, 35778, 74691, 353220, 398278, 58311, 469965, 29646, 431056, 220116, 56280, 60378, 9180, 990, 39903, 246753, 7140, 142311, 46056, 306153, 189420, 17391, 492528, 441330, 316410, 453628, 119805, 263175, 3081, 1035, 111628, 54285, 412686, 62481, 218130, 183315, 273430, 21528, 281625, 68635, 5151, 248865, 95266, 367653, 420903, 15400, 195625, 158766, 19503, 490545, 25651, 152628, 13366, 1081, 357435, 468028, 11325, 37950, 203841, 72771, 144453, 404550, 48205, 27730, 83028, 85078, 3160, 216153, 7260, 117855, 105570, 101475, 9316, 23653, 52326, 1128, 250986, 81003, 64620, 173166, 169071, 87153, 488566, 334971, 312445, 384126, 296065, 339076, 5253, 31878, 33930, 330891, 265356, 451725, 390286, 429201, 289941, 1176, 79003, 439453, 177310, 378015, 165025, 89253, 343206, 3240, 214185, 17578, 302253, 466095, 109746, 146611, 326836, 97461, 187578, 253116, 486591, 29890, 275653, 1225, 201930, 361675, 36046, 396495, 115921, 42195, 11476, 7381, 15576, 193753, 13530, 70876, 44253, 154846, 347361, 50403, 77028, 21736, 283881, 66795, 5356, 9453, 371953, 91378, 19701, 322806, 410871, 3321, 40186, 1275, 419070, 181503, 130305, 212226, 132355, 161028, 484620, 128271, 134421, 25878, 255255, 46360, 308505, 267546, 58653, 449826, 464166, 56616, 126253, 1326, 148785, 351541, 60726, 136503, 103740, 27966, 23871, 402753, 75078, 3403, 437580, 7503, 318801, 38226, 114003, 5460, 427350, 54615, 93528, 124251, 200028, 482653, 99681, 1378, 210276, 17766, 107880, 138601, 11628, 62835, 365940, 9591, 257403, 277885, 13695, 32131, 48516, 292230, 15753, 298378, 171405, 69006, 34191, 185745, 191890, 1431, 157080, 122265, 3486, 462241, 355746, 167331, 382375, 175528, 388521, 52650, 140715, 269745, 480690, 30135, 21945, 447931, 19900, 5565, 150975, 73153, 286146, 314821, 232903, 7626, 234955, 230860, 1485, 304590, 208335, 64980, 376278, 95703, 237016, 417241, 228826, 36315, 394716, 409060, 112101, 120295, 259560, 163306, 83436, 239086, 226801, 3570, 85491, 179700, 42486, 198135, 26106, 142845, 81406, 435711, 9730, 1540, 11781, 44551, 478731, 241165, 224785, 87571, 40470, 337431, 333336, 24090, 425503, 460320, 50721, 17955, 13861, 101926, 5671, 359976, 79401, 28203, 106030, 341551, 329266, 243253, 370230, 222778, 15931, 1596, 280126, 400960, 206403, 118341, 7750, 3655, 46665, 89676, 271953, 310866, 190036, 71253, 446040, 67161, 153181, 261726, 144991, 345696, 159330, 325221, 245350, 38503, 476776, 220780, 77421, 97903, 183921, 58996, 1653, 56953, 294528, 32385, 20100, 110215, 22155, 9870, 5778, 61075, 34453, 196251, 300700, 3741, 91806, 11935, 247456, 54946, 458403, 288420, 218791, 349866, 30381, 1711, 321201, 116403, 169653, 433846, 415416, 173755, 48828, 204480, 7875, 364231, 386760, 474825, 75466, 14028, 147153, 380628, 407253, 63190, 263901, 26335, 165600, 18145, 249571, 36585, 1770, 216811, 423660, 392941, 16110, 52975, 177906, 3828, 24310, 306936, 444153, 274170, 5886, 130816, 69378, 104196, 132870, 282376, 93961, 128778, 155403, 354061, 374545, 317206, 28441, 42778, 10011, 134940, 188191, 100128, 126756, 1830, 456490, 472878, 251695, 114481, 44850, 40755, 214840, 108345, 12090, 161596, 65341, 73536, 8001, 137026, 399171, 202566, 194376, 3916, 20301, 124750, 149331, 182106, 22366, 497503, 51040, 1891, 266085, 5995, 431985, 14196, 139128, 46971, 38781, 368511, 32640, 296835, 253828, 83845, 122760, 358281, 96141, 212878, 290703, 85905, 81810, 313236, 495510, 470935, 413595, 34716, 442270, 18336, 1953, 16290, 30628, 4005, 10153, 276396, 335790, 454581, 87990, 303031, 79800, 331705, 339900, 421821, 141246, 112575, 8128, 26565, 67528, 157641, 405450, 57291, 59340, 71631, 493521, 120786, 24531, 200661, 12246, 171991, 6105, 284635, 327645, 2016, 255970, 344035, 151525, 167910, 102378, 385003, 210925, 55278, 61425, 186355, 90100, 49141, 268278, 77815, 36856, 176121, 106491, 192510, 4095}
0.17399358749389648
```